# How can I allow new R users to send information to a Google Form?

Tags: r

**How can I allow new R users to send information to a Google Form?** (RSelenium requires a bit of set up, at least for headless browsing, so it's not the best candidate IMO but I may be missing something that makes it the best choice).

I have some new R users I want to get responses from interactively and send to a secure location.  I have chosen Google Forms to pass the information to, as it allows one way sends of the info and doesn't allow the user access to the spreadsheet that is created from the form.

Here's a [url of this form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1tz2RPftOLRCQrGSvgJTRELrd9sdIrSZ_kxfoFdHiqD4/viewform):

```
url <- "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1tz2RPftOLRCQrGSvgJTRELrd9sdIrSZ_kxfoFdHiqD4/viewform"
```

To give context here's how I'm using R to interact with the user:

```
question <- function(message, opts = c("Yes", "No")){
    message(message)
    ans <- menu(opts)
    if (ans == "2") FALSE else TRUE
}

question("Was this information helpful?")
```

I want to then send that `TRUE`/`FALSE` to the Google form above.  How can I send a response to the Google Form above from within R in a way that I can embed in code the user will interact with and doesn't require difficult set up by the user?

Add on R packages are fine if they accomplish the task.

Comment: Yes or possible a character comment

Comment: `if (ans == "2") FALSE else TRUE` is a code antipattern. Only use logical constants to initialise variables, and *for nothing else*. What you want to write here is simply `ans != '2'`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph quickie code to demo the point but point taken.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can send a  POST query. Here an example using `httr` package:

For example:

```
library(httr)
send_response<- 
  function(response){
    form_url <- "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1tz2RPftOLRCQrGSvgJTRELrd9sdIrSZ_kxfoFdHiqD4/formResponse"
    POST(form_url,
         query = list(`entry.1651773982`=response)
    )
  }
```

Then you can call it :

```
send_response(question("Was this information helpful?"))
```

Comment: What is `entry.1651773982`?

Comment: Ah it's in the sourse as `entry_`

Comment: @TylerRinker yes it is in the source. The name of the input. You should use the browser to discover names.